# Using a dynamic cell value in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to call the value of a cell to perform a calculation. At first I got an error saying the cell was undefined, so to rectify this I put a value in the cell:

```
With Range("B8")
.Value = 10
.NumberFormat = "0.00\%"
End With
```

but when I try and edit the value of cell B9 the value of the sum doesn't change.

```
Dim PTS As Integer
PTS = Cells(8, 2) / 100 * Cells(2, 2)
Cells(4, 2) = PTS
```

Basically I want Cell(4,2) to change when the value of Cell(B9) is edited on the spreadsheet. I'm pretty new to VBA and have tried a few things (indirect, dynamic etc) but cant get it to work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why you are using `Range("B9"`) when you don't use it in `PTS` ?

Comment: Sounds stupid, but in Excel, when you want range1 to change when range2 is modified, you put a formula in range1, and you don't use VBA.

Comment: Can you step back and explain what you are trying to achieve? If you use Excel, you probably want to perform some calculation. Your first choice would be formulas in the worksheet cells. Explain why you want VBA instead.

Comment: The B9 was a typo.

I need to use VBA as I am taking values from a database and want the equation to compute and display on a new sheet when a button is clicked. 

The only thing I have left to do is make a cell for a percentage level and have the equation PTS change when the value of B8 is modified.

Comment: Lockers answer does what you need

Comment: I want it to be automatic though, I shouldn't need to enter the formula every time i open the sheet, it should be automatic. My problem is that When I edit the vale of the cell B9, my formula  doesn't acknowledge the new value and update

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can just use Excel formulas. Just put `=B9/100*B2` into B4, in or whichever cell you'd like the value to change according to the other cells.

If you prefer or need to use VBA instead, the current mistake I'm seeing is that you've put in Cells(8, 2) instead of Cells(9, 2), and thus trying to calculate from B8 instead of B9.

Comment: I want it to be automatic though, I shouldn't need to enter the formula every time i open the sheet, it should be automatic. My problem is that When I edit the vale of the cell B9, my formula doesn't acknowledge the new value and update